# Обработка событий в datalist

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток. 
Столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть `input` поле с `datalist` списком. Мне необходимо, что бы при нажатии на элемент из `datalist`, происходило какое-либо событие. Тот же `alert`, хотя бы. `$().change` работает, когда поле выходит из фокуса, а нужно, что бы сразу при нажатии. Такое возможно?

```
<input type="text" id="test_input" list="temp_list">
    <datalist id="temp_list">
        <option value="1">
            first
        </option>
        <option value="2">
            second
        </option>
        <option value="3">
            third
        </option>
    </datalist>
```

Comment: [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)?

Comment: Пробовал повесить всевозможные обработчики событий на datalist и на option. И ни один из них не сработал( 
.click в то числе. Если на input поставить click, то он вызывается когда нажимаешь непосредственно на input поле, а datalist отображается ниже и поэтому click с input не работает(

Answer (score 4):

Событие `input` срабатывает тут же при изменении значения текстового элемента и поддерживается всеми браузерами, кроме IE8-.

```js
$('#test_input').on('input', function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test_input" list="temp_list">
<datalist id="temp_list">
        <option value="1">
            first
        </option>
        <option value="2">
            second
        </option>
        <option value="3">
            third
        </option>
    </datalist>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А другого варианта нет? Просто у меня в программе, при заполнении этого поля выполняется ajax-запрос. И с .on('input') при любом нажатии на клавиатуру выполняется этот запрос. Если есть вариант, что бы лишь при нажатии на элемент из списка, я был бы очень благодарен. Ибо сам я не смог найти, как это сделать и знаний не хватает(